# MySQL Workbench Export Completed with 1 Errors - how to see error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using the Export to Disk functionality under Data Export and Restore in the administration part of MySQL workbench I have started getting message like "Export Completed with 1 Errors" (or some other number of errors).  Under that it says "Statistics: Starting" but that never seems to complete.

Simple question: how do I see what the errors are?  I am in the admin section, not the query section, so I do not have an output pane to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another tab in the export section titled "Export Progress". There's also the log:

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. Ok.  looks like I need to upgrade workbench then.  My version has no such tab

Comment: Upgrading is always a good idea. MySQL Workbench is under constant development, with many problems fixed and things improved in each new version.